# Django Variable not getting showed

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have started my Djnago Journey, I am trying to print a defined variable in html file but not getting anything, please let me know whats wrong with the code

my views.py, see the last method where I'm trying to post the data

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse


# Create your views here.


def bootstrappage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def secondpage(request):
    return render(request, 'common.html')


def thirdpage(request):
    var = 'this is my first variable'
    mydictionary = {
        "first": var,
        'two':"data of two"
    }
    print(mydictionary["first"])
    return render(request, 'third.html', context=mydictionary)
```

third.html file where I am trying to print the variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block title %}Third page{% endblock %}
{% block name %}Viewing Third page!{% endblock %}
{{first}}
{{two}}


</body>
</html>
```

index.html file, this is taken from official bootstrap site, basic code of navbar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}bootstrap{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

    <h1>{% block name %}Tiwariji!{% endblock %}</h1>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `{% block content %} {{ first }} {% endblock %}` to your third.html. and in your index.html you also have to put: `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` to get the content from third.html. So the exact same thing as your title. have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language) for the Django template language

Comment: Thanks!! was able to print the variables. But I don't understand why I need to use {% block content %} {% endblock %} in index.html ?? What I am trying here is getting Navbar from index.html and other page specific stuff I'm trying to define in Third.html only.

Comment: Great! That is beacause of template inheritance. Basically that means that you dont have to repeat yourself with code, for example the navbar/footer. So you can just place {%block content %}{% endblock %} under your navbar. this way django only has to render your content, instead of the entire page again, including navbar/footer etc. checkout: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance for more info.